# New section being added in Layout.xml - SummaryLayout

Tags: page-layout, metadata

When I'm using eclipse to retrieve my update layout (after adding new field), for some reason I see additional section being added- SummaryLayout.
Although the only change I did - is add new field.

I saw SF dodumentation, but not clear why it's being added. How it's related to "Case Feed"? I have Feed enable for this object, but I have other objects with Feed enable that doesn't get this section. 
Seems that it happen for specific object (I tried creating new layout for this object and this section is being added, while it's not happen for other objects/layouts).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm

> SummaryLayout Controls the appearance of the highlights panel, which
>   summarizes key fields in a grid at the top of a page layout, when Case
>   Feed is enabled. Available in API version 25.0 and later.

```
<summaryLayout>
        <masterLabel>00h9E000000RZsU</masterLabel>
        <sizeX>4</sizeX>
        <sizeY>0</sizeY>
        <summaryLayoutStyle>Default</summaryLayoutStyle>
    </summaryLayout>
```